# In Google Docs, apply small caps formatting to a part of a line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to write a script in order to replace specific words with their small caps version. I have created a small caps style Heading6 in my document but it can only be applied to a text range as a whole.
Is it possible to apply the style partially?

Here is my attempt:

```
function applyHeading(textToFind){
   var style = {};
   style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING6;
   var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
   var foundElement = body.findText(textToFind);

    while (foundElement != null) {
      // Get the text object from the element
      var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

      // Where in the element is the found text?
      var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
      var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

      var newText = foundText.getText().substring(0, start) + textToFind.toLowerCase() + foundText.getText().substring(end + 1);
      foundText.setText(newText);
      // Set style -- does not work
      foundText.setAttributes(start, end, style);

      // Find the next match
      foundElement = body.findText(textToFind, foundElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you set the style attributes on the containing `Paragraph`? I imagine certain stylings are not actually applied to the text itself. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading

Comment: Yes but it changes the whole paragraph and I want to change a specific word, i. e.:

some text <small caps> some text

Comment: Probably you should not create a *heading* style then. Have your tried other stylings?

Comment: But how can I create a non-heading style in Google docs from some printed text? Unfortunately, I have not found the way.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117682/182986

Comment: @gisly If your issue was resolved, please post it as an answer and accept it. If your issue was still not resolved, can you show the current situation?

Comment: Hi! No, it wasn't resolved. I think it's not possible to do it via the script so I chose not to do it.

Comment: @gisly Thank you for replying. I could understand the current situation. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Document including the input and output you want? I would like to confirm about your current issue. If you cannot provide the sample, don't worry.

Comment: @Tanaike Hi, this is a sample document https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_GErrftV0e6V8WTdd2wkre8AiXGCpCYyCGKJJETrp3o/edit?usp=sharing and this is the script https://script.google.com/d/1LiVpfVdDfadGxe1v6iJFdQiIHlUUSlOsQPdXgut3wv5rGOwWhlrZiI4J/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: @gisly Thank you for replying and sharing the sample Document. From your Document, I could understand about the result you want. So I would like to propose a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this workaround was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @gisly I added a sample script using [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs). Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @gisly Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike! I have tried the script but I keep getting errors in the pure text search part. I would like to investigate ir

Comment: @gisly Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can you provide a sample Document for replicating your situation? I would like to confirm about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to convert the found texts to the small capital letters.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for modifying the part of texts to the small capital letters in Document Service, yet. I think that this might be achieved with Document Service by the future update. But as a current workaround, I thought that Google Docs API released recently might be able to be used for achieving this. So I challenged this.

**In order to use the following sample script, before you run the script, please enable Google Docs API at API console as follows.**

### Enable Google Docs API at API console:

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click "Explore and enable APIs".
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At "Search for APIs & services", input "Docs". And click "Google Docs API".
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

### Flow:

The flow of sample script is as follows.

1. Find texts on Google Document using the findText method of Document Service.
2. Retrieve all contents from Google Document using the get method of Google Docs API.

   - Each content is corresponding to each paragraph of Document.
3. Create ranges of all found texts using the retrieved contents and the objects retrieved by the findText method.
4. Modify the text style of the found texts using the batchUpdate method of Google Docs API.

### Sample script:

The sample script is for the container-bound script with Google Document. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and run the function `sample()`.

```
function applySmallCapital(textToFind) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var baseUrl = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/";
  var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
  var params = {headers: headers};

  // Retrieve all contents from Google Document.
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + id + "?fields=*", params);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

  // In order to use at Google Docs API, create ranges of found texts.
  var foundElement = body.findText(textToFind);
  var ranges = [];
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var p = foundElement.getElement();
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) p = p.getParent();
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH || p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      var content = obj.body.content[body.getChildIndex(p) + 1];
      ranges.push({
        startIndex: content.startIndex + foundElement.getStartOffset(),
        endIndex: content.startIndex + foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
      });
    }
    foundElement = body.findText(textToFind, foundElement);
  }

  // Modify textStyle of found texts.
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    var resource = {requests: ranges.map(function(e) {return {
      updateTextStyle: {
        textStyle: {smallCaps: true},
        range: e,
        fields: "smallCaps"}
      }
    })};
    params.method = "post";
    params.contentType = "application/json";
    params.payload = JSON.stringify(resource);
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + id + ":batchUpdate", params);
  }
}

function sample() {
  applySmallCapital("this should be small caps");
}
```

### Result:

#### From:

[image]

#### To:

[image]

- For testing this script, your sample texts in your shared Document was used. You can see that the text of "this should be small caps" is modified to the small capital letters.

### References:

- [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/)
- [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TextStyle)
- [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/)

### Added:

When Google Docs API of Advanced Google Services is used, the above script becomes as follows. When you use this, please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google Services. In this script, the cost became a bit lower than that of above by reducing one loop.

```
function applySmallCapital(textToFind) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var id = doc.getId();

  // Retrieve all contents from Google Document.
  var obj = Docs.Documents.get(id, {fields: "*"})

  // In order to use at Google Docs API, create ranges of found texts.
  var foundElement = body.findText(textToFind);
  var requests = [];
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var p = foundElement.getElement();
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) p = p.getParent();
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH || p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      var content = obj.body.content[body.getChildIndex(p) + 1];
      requests.push({
      updateTextStyle: {
        textStyle: {smallCaps: true},
        range: {
          startIndex: content.startIndex + foundElement.getStartOffset(),
          endIndex: content.startIndex + foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
        },
        fields: "smallCaps"}
      });
    }
    foundElement = body.findText(textToFind, foundElement);
  }

  // Modify textStyle of found texts.
  if (requests.length > 0) {
    var resource = {requests: requests};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, id);
  }
}

function sample() {
  applySmallCapital("this should be small caps");
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs)

Comment: Have you tried the Docs client library yet? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for the information. I had never known that the Advanced Docs Service had already been released. This is a good news. So I added the modified script using it.